# How do I test stability of a MIMO system?

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, transfer-function, control-systems, autoregressive-model

Let's say I have a system similar to two interconnected IIR filters described like this:

\begin{align}
x_1(t)&=a_{11} x_1(t-1)+a_{12} x_1(t-2) +a_{13} x_2(t-1) + a_{14} x_2(t-2)+y_1(t)\\
x_2(t)&=a_{21} x_2(t-1)+a_{22} x_2(t-2) +a_{23} x_1(t-1) + a_{24} x_1(t-2)+y_2(t)
\end{align}

where $x$ are the outputs and $y$ are the inputs.

How would I go about testing the stability of such a system?

I myself have pretty much no background in MIMO systems, so I'm not really sure where even to start.

For a SISO system, I'd start with poles and zeros and go on from there, but I'm not sure how such a graph might looks like in the MIMO case.

Comment: Try writing the system in state space form and looking at the [eigenvalues of the state transition matrix.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Stability#Poles_and_Eigenvalues)

Comment: @Peter K.♦ Thanks, I'll take a look at that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to make your system into a state space representation with state:
$$
\mathbf{x}(t) = \left [ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_1(t)\\
x_2(t)\\
x_1(t-1)\\
x_2(t-1)\\
\end{array}
\right ]
$$
so that
$$
\mathbf{x}(t) = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}(t-1) + \mathbf{y}(t)
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{A} =
\left [ \begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\
1   & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0   & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right ]
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{y}(t) = \left [ 
\begin{array}{c}
y_1(t)\\
y_2(t)\\
0\\
0
\end{array}
\right ]
$$
or you could make $\mathbf{y}$ $2 \times 1$ and introduce a $\mathbf{B}$ matrix.

The system **may** be unstable if the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ are outside the unit circle.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This pushed me in the right direction.